# Prevent deselect date UWP Calendar Control

Tags: c#, uwp, calendar, windows

My application date is required , if i double click date in calender control , getting null Date , i want disable double click how to do that ? below i added my code

```
  <CalendarDatePicker
                        Name="calendarPicker"
                        Width="250"
                        Margin="30,10,10,10"
                        Date="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                     
                        MaxDate="{Binding MaxDateTime}"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"`?

Comment: yes i tried but not working

Comment: If it's not working, you would need to do judgement in C# code by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to accomplish this via a property, but you can accomplish this by adding an event handler on the DateChanged event. You'll want to make sure you have a default value or value assigned to the `CalendarDatePicker` to start off or this may cause problems.

```
  <CalendarDatePicker
                        Name="calendarPicker"
                        Width="250"
                        Margin="30,10,10,10"
                        Date="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                     
                        MaxDate="{Binding MaxDateTime}"
                        DateChanged="DatePicker_DateChanged"/>
```

and then adding this in the code behind for the XAML page:

```
private void DatePicker_DateChanged(CalendarDatePicker sender, CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!sender.Date.HasValue) sender.Date = args.OldDate;
}
```